# How to keyword completion word with joined -?

Tags: vim

I want to keyword complete with joined word by `-` .
Default's Vim is can't understand `.post-header` is one word.

But I want to make vim recognise `.post-header` is one word.
If they so ,I think keyword completion is works when word is joined by `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `:help 'iskeyword'`: `-` is not part of the default list so you must add it yourself:

```
:set iskeyword+=-
```

If you want it only for CSS, add the line below to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/css.vim`:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=-
```

You must create that file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Very useful. I found that defining a filetype-specific version needs to go in the `~/.vim/after/syntax` directory rather than the `ftplugin` directory, otherwise the `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/` version can overwrite the changes.